# Delphi 2009 Actionmanager default Imagelist

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, taction, timagelist, tactionmanager

I have just started a new project, and I am using the Delphi 2009 Actionmanager component for the first time. 
The Actionmanager has a list of standard actions, which gives me actions such as File open / save without any coding - great stuff. Is there a standard ImageList to go with this, with the correct images for the default ImageIndex populated by the ActionManager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you connect your ActionManager with an TImageList before you fill in the standard actions then delphi copies the icons of these actions automatically in the attached ImageList (tested with Delphi 2010).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it does not seem to also populate the DisablesImages list the same way. Bother. Back to the glyph list then....